# Being notified of the comments under the answer of someone else to your post

Tags: support, feature-request, comments, comment-notification

Sometimes a lot of good things happen as the comments under an answer to your post. Though we are notified of the answers given or the comments under the body of the post, it seems that we are not notified of such comments. Is there any way to add a feature for being notified of such comments?

Comment: There are no notifications about comments under an answer to one's question. If you would like to change this, or make it possible to switch such notifications on if one wants so, you could make a feature request.

Comment: @StefanKohl would it be enough to add the feature request tag to the current post?

Comment: If you rewrite this post as a concrete feature request instead of a question, then yes.

Comment: Probably you could be able to achieve this with [StackEye - Chrome Extension to follow users and questions on StackExchange sites](https://stackapps.com/q/4454). (I have not tried it myself, so I am hesitant to post this as an answer.)

Comment: I have seen this mentioned a few times in discussions on Mathematics Meta - so you can look there (or on the main meta) whether also some other advice given there might be useful for you. Here are some posts from Mathematics Meta: [Is there any way to subscribe to a thread so you get email notifications?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21214), [A way to “watch” questions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6994), [Can I follow a question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11783), [Mark problems as “notify me if answer is posted”?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4867)

Comment: I will also add that you can add questions to your [favorites](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/favorites/info). This does not give you notifications, but IIRC when something happens on the question (new answer, new comment, etc.) it gets highlighted on favorite tab.

Comment: Now there is a possibility to follow a post (which includes possibility to follow an answer to your question). Links to more information can be found [in the corresponding tag-info](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/follow-post/info).

Answer (score 1):

Yea it's kind of ridiculous not to have that capability of atleast  being notified by email when someone answer's your question or in fact any others in which u may be interested. Also haven't even seen a good answer or way to see your prior questions or answers again.

Comment: In fact, for answers to your questions and for comments on *your* posts you get notifications to your inbox. And depending on preferences you set up in your profile, you can also use email notifications (Edt Profile & Settings/Edit Email Settings). See also: [Does Stack Exchange have email notification option?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122320) This feature request is about notification related to activity on posts of other users.

Comment: Regarding the way to see your prior posts - on your profile you can see both your [questions](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/users/current?tab=questions) and [answers](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/users/current?tab=answers).

Comment: Sorry I see that by mistake I have put links to profile on *meta* rather than on the *main site* in the previous link. On the main site, you can also find both [questions](https://mathoverflow.net/users/current?tab=questions) and [answers](https://mathoverflow.net/users/current?tab=answers) in your profile page. (Sorry for the confusion.)