# How to follow a question?

Tags: support, feature-request, notifications, follow-post

Basically, is it possible to follow a question by another user? Meaning whenever there are new answers or comments on it, I get a notification in my inbox, the same way the original poster of the question does.

Comment: This previous post is somewhat different: [Being notified of the comments under the answer of someone else to your post](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2150). But in the comments you can see some related links to discussions on Mathematics Meta and also a userscript on Stack Apps.

Comment: I will add that there are several similar feature requests on Meta Stack Exchange. You can probably find more. The posts are rather old and the topic seems to reappear quite often. Here are a few: 
[Mark questions to receive notifications and updates?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803),
[Subscribe to others' questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/34481),
[Subscribing to questions and comments that don't belong to you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45360),
[Adding Favorites to the Stack Exchange global inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83343).

Comment: Thanks for the links. It seems the most convenient solution is to mark a question as a favorite. This does not provide exactly the same notifications as you get from your own questions but essentially all the information is there. I will try that.

Comment: The other possibility is the "question feed" at the bottom right of the question page.

Answer (score 4):

Just added.  A "Follow" feature.

> [image: pic]

Pointers to further information about this feature can be found in the [corresponding tag-info on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/follow-post/info).

Comment: Relevant posts on [meta.se]: [The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661) and the older one [Upcoming Feature: Follow Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345148)..