# Try "question feed"

Tags: discussion, comment-notification, notifications, rss

From another meta [question](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4089/454) here, I guess this is a little-known feature.

Look at a question page on MO.  On the right, below `BLOG, HOT META POSTS, Related` etc., you will find:

[image]

Click on that to add yourself to the "feed" for that question.  How it works, I think, depends on how your computer has been configured.  In my case, these notifications arrive in my "News".

I note that there is a "user feed" at the bottom of a user's profile page, so it seems you can sign up to be notified of whatever that user posts.  Look around.  You may find other feeds as well.

Comment: I suppose there is a "tag feed" as well, associated to each tag.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki This post is relatively old, but it might be interesting in this context, since it lists many various feeds: [What other hidden or inobvious RSS feeds are available on Stack Exchange and its sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151519)

Comment: @jeq Often (always?) when you search for some tags, you can see also a feed there. For example, if I search for questions in tags [(lo.logic) or (reverse-math)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/lo.logic+or+reverse-math), I can see feed called "recently active lo.logic or reverse-math questions feed" on the right. (The "recently active" part is dependent on the sorting I have used.) Several feeds for featured questions in a specific tag are posted [in the Listing bounties chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/70737/listing-bounties?tab=feeds).

Comment: @GeraldEdgar You probably have more experience with feeds than I do - when you use this "question feed", it shows when a new answer is posted - but not comments on the question or on answer, right?

Comment: If, instead of clicking on "question feed", you "download linked file", you get an XML file showing the recent activity for the question.  Full text: questions, answers, comments.  Presumably you need to set up RSS to work on your computer.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar I am not sure whether your comment is intended to say that your RSS gets also new comments (not just answers). If yes, could you perhaps add a screenshot showing this? I do not think that what you wrote in the previous comment is really correct. For example, you can see that your comment is not shown anywhere in the feed [for this question](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/feeds/question/4090). Here is [a screenshot](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48725324#48725324) showing what I got from the feed for this question.

Comment: I know very little about RSS, so you may be right.

Answer (score 1):

Since feeds might be new to many users around here, I have created [a separate chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/88817/2019/1/25) for people who want to experiment with them a bit. (And maybe later decide whether they want to start using some [software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_feed_aggregators) or browser extension for this - if they see that it is useful.)

- Unless you are a moderator, you need to be a room owner if you want to edit the feeds for the room. If you want to try them, feel free to ping me in that room and when I am around I will add you to room owners.
- You can add new feeds to the room [in the feeds tab](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/88817/experimenting-with-feeds?tab=feeds). You have two options: Add a feed as a live ticker (so the new items will only shown to the users currently in room and it will appear as a notification at a top of the room which can be dismissed) or as regular chat messages (i.e., the new items appear as a regular messages in the chatroom and stay in the transcript.

Of course, feel free to use the room for any other purposes related to this topic. (E.g., discussing which software to use for aggregating feeds, where to find useful feeds on MathOverflow and in Stack Exchange network, etc.)

After people are done experimenting we can simply let the room go. (The room [gets frozen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/frozen-rooms/info) after 14 days of inactivity. The cut-off is shortened to 7 days if only one user posted in the room.)